# Ways to avoid isnull in the where clause of an update statement

Tags: sql-server

I think I generally understand why and how to avoid `isnull` in `where` clauses (generally a performance drop).  But I've become a little stumped on how to do it specifically for a certain type of `update` statement.  Or at least how to do it in an elegant and readable way.

The type of `update` statement I refer to is one where I have a default value and an override value.  I will only update a few records out of millions, so I do not want to just blindly update all records.

```
update m set OpenDate = isnull(c.OverrideDate, c.OpenDate)
from matters m
inner join clients c on c.clientID = m.clientID
where m.OpenDate <> isnull(c.OverrideDate, c.OpenDate)
```

My gut is telling me that I'll have to split it into 2 `update` statements.

```
update m set OpenDate = c.OpenDate
from matters m
inner join clients c on c.clientID = m.clientID
where m.OpenDate <> c.OpenDate
   and c.OverrideDate is null

update m set OpenDate = c.OverrideDate
from matters m
inner join clients c on c.clientID = m.clientID
where c.OverrideDate is not null
   and m.OpenDate <> c.OverrideDate
```

It just feels like it could be consolidated.  But I don't want the `isnull` clause to cause the update statement to use a scan of the table instead of a seek using an index.

Answer (score 0):

If `m.OpenDate` is allowed to be `NULL` then you will need to make an adjustment to the criteria.

```
    WHERE ISNULL(m.OpenDate,'1/1/1900') <> ISNULL(c.OverrideDate, c.OpenDate)
```

Comment: The point of my question is to eliminate isnull from the where clause.  Thank you anyway for your observation.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want update same records with same condition.

I prefer you update in one round trip because of performance issue.

ISNULL(A,B) means if A is null then replace with B else A is not null use A. Then it is seems good:

```
update m set OpenDate = isnull(c.OverrideDate, c.OpenDate)
from matters m
inner join clients c on c.clientID = m.clientID
where m.OpenDate <> isnull(c.OverrideDate, c.OpenDate)
```

Comment: That's the query I started with.  The issue here is that putting `isnull` in the where clause can generate a scan over the entire table instead of using a seek on an index.  Given that I am updating a few records out of millions, this is not good for performance.